# Exported charts won't work in certain folders?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4.5

My exported charts won't work depending on where I move the bin-debug folder.

They work if I move it from my workspace:

```
C:\Users\Flexer\Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\charts\bin-debug
```

to my desktop:

```
C:\Users\Flexer\Desktop\bin-debug
```

But not if I move it to:

```
C:\Users\Flexer\Desktop\test\bin-debug
```

or

```
C:\bin-debug
```

What's going on?

Mats

Answer (score 0):

You mean they don't operate, as opposed to not loading your data?

In your project properties, Flex Build Path - Library Path, assure you are merging into code dependent libraries.  Otherwise, be sure SWC, SWZ, RSL also exist at the location you move your application.

[image]

Comment: The SWFs won't load when I open their HTMLs. All the include files are present - the only thing changing is the location of the bin-debug folder.

Comment: If you export a release build to a unique location, does your SWF load?